# Content sliders: valid usage for tables, lists, etc

Tags: html, css, accessibility, markup, carousel

Content sliders, like [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) or Bootstrap's [carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel), use `div`s  to define *slides*. This is great for images and many other elements but it doesn't make much sense for things like lists or tables (and probably more).

---

#### List example #1:

```
<div><!--slider container-->
    <ul>
        <div class="active"><!--currently shown slide-->
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
        </div>
        <div><!--another slide-->
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

This is not valid.

---

#### List example #2:

```
<div><!--slider container-->
    <div class="active"><!--currently shown slide-->
         <ul>
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <div><!--another slide-->
         <ul>
            <li>Blah</li>
            <li>Blah</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is valid but just does not make sense, is poor from an accessibility point of view, and so on.

---

### Is there a right way of spreading tables, lists, etc. across multiple slides?

### Is there a way of creating a content slider using the valid markup for a table/list?*

---

Perhaps HTML5 brings something to the table which could help (but I doubt it).

* Reason for the CSS tag

Comment: Do you want to equally distribute the list items for each slide?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Nope. In my case, I'm actually using a table but for this example a list is just simpler but carries the relevance to the problem. So, for example, I'd like a maximum of 10 table rows per slide. If there's 15 then there would be 10 in the first, 5 in the second.

Comment: Ah... That's what I asked. In that case, you NEED to do a heavy DOM traversal. Count the numbers, check the length, and append those inside the tables. Like, you need to give breaks, for instance, take this: `insert('</ul></div><div><ul>')` - some sort of it right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar So you're suggesting that I display the table as is, then when the dom is ready: re-do the structure and split it into slides (by inserting `divs`, etc.)? It's still going to be invalid html though

Comment: I would also suggest splitting the table up into several tables after the DOM has loaded. I know there are sliders that allow for a single `ul` yet displaying any number of `li`s for each slide. With tables I don't see how it would be done though.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `<section>`-stuff:

```
<div><!--slider container-->
    <section><!--currently shown slide-->
        <p>Blah, blah, blah!</p>
    </section>
    <section><!--another slide-->
         <p>Blah, blah, blah!</p>
    </section>
    </div>
```

A `<ul>` is fine, as the information is a list. 
Do you slide lists? I can't image more you show a image with a few words. Then, just `<p>`.

Comment: I understand how to use a slider for text, images, etc. If your content is a list, then it should be a list. If your content is tabular data, show it in a table. I don't see why one shouldn't use a slider, personal styling preferences aside